# What does the word Umbraco Mean

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

What does the word `Umbraco` mean; the etymology. If it's a made up word, does anyone know the history behind it?

I know this may be slightly off-topic, can't find the right forum for it. Feel free to edit it into right location.

Comment: childish downvoters. downvotes on good questions are for kids.

Comment: "can't find the right forum for it" ... Did you not think of trying Umbraco's forum? Not slightly off-topic, completely off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or software development.

Comment: @pang why hasn't this question been closed?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, it's off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this page: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/about/what-does-umbraco-mean

"The name comes from the Danish word for an Allen (hex) key - the kind you get with Ikea flatpack"

It is actually a modification of the word <strike>"unbrako,"</strike> "unbrakonøgle," (correction thanks to [5arx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2671514/5arx)'s [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238216/what-does-the-word-umbraco-mean/26238300?noredirect=1#comment51242858_26238300)) which means "A hex key or Allen key or wrench is a tool of hexagonal cross-section used to drive bolts and screws that have a hexagonal socket in the head."

For a more detailed explanation, probably with more of the 'history' that you're looking for, you can check out Doug Robar's explanation from the 2010 Umbraco festival. Here is the link to the page with the video on it: http://2010.umbracoukfestival.co.uk/

He's the fourth one down.

Comment: thanks! a great void in my soul has just been fulfilled by this information.

Comment: @5arx thansk for the correction - I've updated the answer